# Как инициализировать плагин jQuery в ангуляр приложении

Tags: json, angularjs

Привет знатоки, нужна помощь ... 
Через ul > li ng-repeat вывожу меню. Для элемента li содержащего условие в JSON  (true), нужно добавить атрибут data-uk-dropdown для работы плагина jQuery. Заранее спасибо)

**html**

```
<nav ng-controller="MenuController as vm" >
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in vm.menu" ng-class="vm.getClass('{{ item.path }}') ? 'active' : '' || (item.submenu === true) ? 'parent' : ''" >
            <a href="{{ item.path }}">{{item.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**JS**

```
.controller('MenuController', MenuController)
function MenuController($location, $http) {
    var vm = this;
    $http.get('menu.json').success(function(data) {
            vm.menu = data;
            vm.submenus = function(index) {
                var result = data[index].pages;
            return result;
        };
    };
    vm.getClass = function(path) {
        return ($location.path() === path) ? 'active' : '';
    };
}
```

**JSON**

```
[{
    "name": "Меню 1",
    "path": "/",
    "submenu": false
}, {
    "name": "Меню 2",
    "path": "#",
    "submenu": true
}, {
    "name": "Меню 3",
    "path": "/menu3",
    "submenu": false
}]
```

Comment: для чего нужен этот атрибут?

Comment: @Grundy для выпадающего меню (http://getuikit.com/docs/dropdown.html)

Comment: это меню плагин jQuery? директива ангуляра? или что-то еще? Судя по всему простым добавлением атрибута не обойтись

Comment: @Grundy да, он работает через jQuery

Comment: тогда на самом деле вопрос можно перефразировать так: как инициализировать плагин jQuery в ангуляр приложении

Comment: @Grundy исправил

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45464/discussion-between-sashatexb-and-grundy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй вот так:

```
<nav ng-controller="MenuController as vm" >
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat-start="item in vm.menu" 
            ng-class="vm.getClass('{{ item.path }}') ? 'active' : '' || (item.submenu === true) ? 'parent' : ''" 
            ng-if="item.submenu" data-uk-dropdown > 
            <a href="{{ item.path }}">{{item.name}}</a> 
        </li> 
        <li ng-repeat-end 
            ng-class="vm.getClass('{{ item.path }}') ? 'active' : '' || (item.submenu === true) ? 'parent' : ''" 
            ng-if="!item.submenu" > 
            <a href="{{ item.path }}">{{item.name}}</a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```